# Do i still need to write media queries if i have built a site using bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries

```html
  <section class="hero py-5" id="home">
    <div class="container-fluid py-5">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="feature-box">
              <h1  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1600"><span>Hello I'm</span> <br>Mahnoor Khan</h1>
              <h5 class="pt-3">Front-end-Developer </h5>
              <div class="button">
              <a href="#contact" class="btn-one">Contact</a>
              <a href="#portfolio" class="btn-two">My Portfolio</a>
</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <img data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="1000" src="./images/hero-img.png" class="feature-img">
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have built my portfolio website using bootstrap but it is not responsive at all?? how to add custom media queries and on what sizes should I focus?

Comment: At the moment is really popular flex display for arranging blocks, check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ... also bootstrap provide basic media-queries that are used by most of the websites so there is no need to implement your own, can be seen here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/

Comment: ok, should I add display flex property to every container to fix the issue?

Comment: i have used container-fluid for every container

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You question is too broad and largely opinion-based. You'll need to revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: And if you used Bootstrap correctly, it's responsive out of the box. The Bootstrap philosophy is "mobile first". That's why we need to see your work.

Comment: Can i share my GitHub repository
 so that you can review my code and help me identify my mistake?

Comment: edit your question with some code to see ;) all repo is not neccessary

Comment: done you can review my code now